# Getting empty hidden values after form submit

Tags: javascript

I want to store some data on client side for that I create a JavaScript code, but, after form submit, i'm getting empty hidden field values. How to fix this?

```js
fid = 1100124686694263;
user = Akshay Barpute;
document.getElementById('fid1').value = fid;
document.getElementById('user1').value = user;
```

```html
Welcome Fill below information to setup your account</br>
<form action='fb1.php' method='post'>
  Enter your email:
  <input type='email' name='emailid'>
  </br>
  Select examination:
  <input type='radio' name='jungle' value='GRE'>GRE& nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type='radio' name='jungle' value='GMAT'>GMAT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type='radio' name='jungle' value='CAD'>CAD&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type='radio' name='jungle' value='MBA CET'>MBA CET&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type='radio' name='jungle' value='others'>others(includes bank & it company exams)
  <br>
  <input type='hidden' name='fid' id='fid1' value=''>
  <input type='hidden' name='user' id='user1' value=''>
  <input type='submit' name='sub' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: `</br>`??? Anyway, `user=Akshay Barpute;` is not valid JavaScript, so it's not running, so you get empty values. Next time check the console.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but try using `&emsp;` instead of repeated `&nbsp;`s, you might get better result.

Comment: Thank You! That solved the problem.

Comment: Actually, i was implementing login with facebook on my website freetests4u.com . The above code is printed by php echo method after satisfying condition. Thats why I'm using </br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `user` expects a string type:

```
fid = 1100124686694263;
user = "Akshay Barpute";
document.getElementById('fid1').value = fid;
document.getElementById('user1').value = user;
```